# Python: Submitting a Form with Requests

Tags: python, forms, python-2.7, post, python-requests

Technically I have two separate questions here. The first is to make sure I'm doing this properly in the first place. Say for a page with the source code such as: https://pastebin.com/raw/N5rRAVh4 would I submit the form by doing the following:

```
payload = {
'checkout[shipping_address][first_name]': 'John',
'checkout[shipping_address][last_name]': 'Doe',
}
requests.post(url, data=payload)
```

Second, if the above format is correct how would I go about submitting a form on a page with the source code such as: https://pastebin.com/raw/VjUAcchj
This one confuses me because there is no name for each element such as `checkout[shipping_address][first_name]` in the first example.

Answer (score 0):

Use id instead of name of input tag
like :

```
payload = {
'checkout_shipping_address_first_name': 'John',
'checkout_shipping_address_last_name': 'Doe',
}
requests.post(url, data=payload)
```

Also you may see this answer:-

[How to input values and click button with Requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36589086/how-to-input-values-and-click-button-with-requests)

Comment: That answers my first question but there are no id's for each element in the second link posted in the question

Comment: @DanteArcese , if you can't find the headers, have a look in firebug or chrome developer tools. There you can see how the post request is made. See the answer here :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35875865/using-python-requests-module-to-submit-a-form-without-input-name

Comment: I did as you suggested and found one POST request that had the following headers and form data, but that POST didn't have anything including credit card info so I found another POST request that had the following headers and payload. Both are included here: https://pastebin.com/raw/NmnrKyNL (don't worry, the credit card info at the bottom is fake)

Comment: @DanteArcese the website you are trying has tons of encryption algos applied. You will be needing to analyse all frontend code to get to it. The bank tech is not that stupid to send your data payload as it is without encryption. Doing this may lead to hacking of your bank details